# Does marginal effects change depending on the size and heterogeneity of the population?

Tags: logistic, marginal-effect

I am trying to predict the probability of receiving treatment using a logit regression. I have two regressions with the same explanatory variables:

- Regression 1:  I predict the probability of treatment in the entire
  population (about 6000 received treatment out of about 5 million
  observations)
- Regression 2: I predict the probability of treatment in a
  subpopulation that received a referral for treatment (about 6000
  received treatment out of about 20 thousand     observations)

The marginal effects of the explanatory variables are much larger and more significant in regression 2.

**Question: can this be explained by the size and heterogeneity of the underlying dataset?**

Thank you.